# Где найти информацию о системных Intent в Android?

Tags: android

Добрый день. начал учить андроид и сейчас изучаю явные и неявные интенты.
Вот так открываю контакты из приложения

---

```
public void openContactList(View v)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
     startActivity(intent);
    }
```

---

**Возник вопрос:**

например, мне нужно открыть смс список или ,скажем, календарь. вот где взять эту (Intent.ACTION_PICK) , а *особенно эту* (ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI) часть кода? *Может кто кинуть силку на раздел в документации или статьи где это описано?*

Answer (score 5):

Официальная документация Android - класс [Intent](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/content/Intent.html)

Официальная документация Android - [описание класса Intent](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/guide/components/intents-filters.html)

Answer (score 2):

Могу посоветовать хорошую библиотечку, сильно упрощающую работу с неявными интентами. В доках можете найти их список. https://github.com/marvinlabs/android-intents